# Apache ProxyPass not loading Resources

Tags: linux, apache, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I configured apache proxypass and it's working but not loading images, javascript, CSS etc... I want to proxypass to another server, not localhost. Below is my configuration.

[see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhITo.png)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.server.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain

    RewriteEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass /apm http://192.168.1.102:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse /apm http://192.168.1.102:9999/

</virtualHost>
```

Comment: add another entry for /  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.102:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.102:9999/ and give it another try

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research and reading some tutorials I got a solution.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.server.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain

    RewriteEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.102:9999/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.102:9999/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: how would you sole it if you were to hide multiple servers behind 1 proxy e.g.:

    /apm -> http://192.168.1.102:9999/
and
    /abc -> http://192.168.1.102:9998/
?

Comment: What if you have to configure reverse proxy for multiple backend servers?