# Apache ProxyPass loading Resources only if I use "/" (not in another path)

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, apache, proxy

I'm trying to load React in another port with Apache.
I'm using in Apache Config file:

```
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:3000/
```

This shows my index.html, but not my React resources (images, js...) (in **localhost/node**)

[I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217583/apache-proxypass-not-loading-resources) and if I change the directory it works  (in **localhost/**):

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
```

but I don't want to use my "/" because I want to combine two ports working on time showing one site within another.

¿How can I load correctly my port 3000 in **localhost/node**?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

From mod_proxy docs:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Add ProxyPassReverse directive and quotes:

> ProxyPass "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
>
> ProxyPassReverse "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"

Comment: would it really help? how does it work? could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217583/apache-proxypass-not-loading-resources