# Apache reverse proxy not loading resources

Tags: linux, docker, apache, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

I've configured proxy reverse with apache 2.4 on a server (ip for example `192.168.1.10`) as follows:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass "/foo/" "http://172.20.0.3/"
ProxyPassReverse "/foo/" "http://172.20.0.3/"
```

`mod_proxy_html` is loaded.

Where `172.20.0.3` is a docker container, hosted by the server.
When I browse to `192.168.1.10/foo/` I see on the url bar `192.168.1.10/index.php` (`index.php` is the page I actually would like to browse), but the resources required to load `index.php` are not found. So I get `404 page not found`.

Setting `/` instead of `/foo` works, but I need to configure other proxy on the same server too.

This Q/A does not provide solution for my case: [Apache ProxyPass not loading Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217583/apache-proxypass-not-loading-resources)

What I'm missing? Thank you